# Modify image displayed in called activity by parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

This is what I want to do (my current code to follow):

Use 1 onclick listener for all my buttons on my main activity (I believe I found the correct implementation - please see code to make any suggestions).  Have the button click start a new activity; however, based on which button was pressed modify the image displayed in the called activity's xml.  I've successfully modified the image (of the called xml) so that when I click a button, the image I set is successfully displayed.

This is where it gets strange, after my 'set' image is displayed, the placeholder image that I set in the xml code is displayed immediately after my 'set' image.

Then the back button on the phone goes back to the image that I programmatically 'set' and another back button press on the phone closes the app.

What am I doing wrong?

My code follows:

MainActivity onCreate method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton b01 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton01);
    b01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.image);
            ImageView iview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            iview.setImageResource(R.drawable.amiga);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyImage.class));
        }
    }); 
}
```

MyImage Activity:

```
public class MyImage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
}
}
```

Layout Image.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Image"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post `activity_main.xml` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is not good. It is not good have `setContentView` twice for the same activity.

Each Activity has its own layout.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Instead you can pass the resource id of the image and set the image to imageview in `MyImage`.

Based on what button you click you can pass the appropriate resource id.

So change to

```
  b01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyImage.class);
        i.putExtra("key",R.drawable.amiga);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

In `MyImage`

```
public class MyImage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
    ImageView iview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int resid = getIntent().getIntExtra("key");
    iview.setImageResource(resid);    
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works like a charm.  I am going with this answer as it 'fits' into my current boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

in activity_main.xml create ImageView (ID : imageview), try this code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton b01 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton01);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id.imageview);
    int count = 0;

    Int[] image_array = {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image};

    view.setImageResource(image_array[count]);

    b01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(count < image_array.lenght)
               count++;
           else
               count = 0;
           view.setImageResource(image_array[count]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `ImageView` is not in `activtiy_main.xml`. Your code will give NPE. and op wants to change the image in `MyImage`